# Integration over annulus with infinite outer radius as an integral over a half-space

Tags: integration, mobius-transformation

If I have an integral over an infinite annulus $\mathcal{A} = \{(x, y)~|~x^{2} + y^{2} \geq R \}$, is there a way to transform the variable of integration/coordinates so that the integral is over a half-space? In the case of rotationally symmetric integrand, $\int_{R}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\rho  d\phi\rho f(\rho)$ becomes some integral over $x,y$ which is now rectangular?

Comment: Integrate over the full space, then subtract off the integral over the disk of radius $R$.

Comment: The fact you've tagged the question (mobius-transformations) suggests you know the answer: just use a Mobius transformation.

Comment: I guess I ask because I've seen Mobius transformations of a disk to a rectangle. However, in the case I am interested $f(\rho)$ is not defined for $\rho < R$, so it really needs to be an annulus into a rectangle.

Comment: Huh? No Mobius transformation can turn a disk into a rectangle, or an annulus into a rectangle. You can use a [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform#Complex_homography) to map the upper half-plane to the unit disk (or its inverse to do the opposite) within the complex plane.